# Jquery AJAX json - not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I can not connect to a Web service, tried a lot of different options and change parameters, prompt where to dig? This is my first experience of connecting via AJAX, I tried through other clients work.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
     url: webserUrl,
     type: "GET",
     data: JSON.stringify({ "Tabn": "1","Vaccurrent": "1","Vacnext": "1" }),
     cache: false,
     crossDomain: true,
     username: "user", 
     password: "password",
     processData: false,
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
     headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
     xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
                },
     crossDomain: true,
      success: OnSuccess, 
      error: OnError
        });

        function OnSuccess(data, status)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
    function OnError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error)
    {
        alert('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' + 
            'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
            'xhr.statusText = '  + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
            'request = ' + request + '\n' +
            'error = ' + error);
            console.log('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' + 
            'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
            'xhr.statusText = '  + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
            'request = ' + request + '\n' +
            'error = ' + error);
    }

 });
```

Error:

xrs.status = 200

thrown error = undefined

xhr.statusText = OK

request = undefined

error = undefined

Comment: So what does the xhr.responseText look like?

Comment: Since you're getting a `200` response code, the HTTP request is going through correctly. I suspect the server isn't returning a JSON response, so jQuery is getting an error when it tries to parse the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xrs.status = 200` means the server accepted the request, thus the problem might be on the client side, and most likely is caused by the `"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"` header, which instructs jquery to reject the server response if it didn't sent a json as a response.

You need to check what data is the server responding by using the developer tools your browser provides.

Comment: What and how you can check the last statement?

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov If you're using Chrome, [here's the link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), you're interested about the `Network` tab, for `Firefox` I recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers, changed to a url with wsdl endpoint, also changed the content type to: "text / xml; charset = \" utf-8 \ "" and it worked.

Comment: So are you returning XML to your Ajax? And if you return JSON as a result, you must use application/json as contentType.